# Jquery ajax doesent run from smartphone screen

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ajax

When I click a button an animation runs but the ajax is skipped. This is only a problem on the smartphone screen and not on my computer.

Jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#thisid').hide();

        $("#button-create").on('touchstart',(function(event) {
           var name = $("#create").val();
            var name2 = $("#create2").val();
           $("#stage").load('result.php', {name:name, name2:name2} );

        });
     });
  </script>
```

Button:

```
<button id="button-create" class="btn1">Create</button>
```

Html

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col" style="text-align:center;">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col" style="margin-top:20px;text-   align:center;"> 
   <input type="input" style="height:24px; margin-right:15px;" id="create"   value="Heading">
   <button id="button-create" class="btn1">Create</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<input type="input" style="float:right; display:none;" id="create2" value="<?php echo $_GET['user']?>">
<div id="stage">
</div>
<input type="input" id="headv" size="40" style="display:none;">
<div id="stage100">
</div>
```

Result.php

```
<?php



if( $_REQUEST["name"] )
{
$name = $_REQUEST['name'];
$name1_preg = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);
$name2 = $_RsEQUEST['name2'];
$content = 'Click to edit me, press the save button to save';




session_start();


try {
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e) {

}


$query123 = $pdo->
prepare("INSERT INTO post (head, user, content)   VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$query123->
bindValue(1, $name1_preg);
$query123->
bindValue(2, $name2);
$query123->
bindValue(3, $content);
$query123->
execute();

}

?>
```

Comment: try touchstart instead of click. smartphones don't recognize the click events. try $("#button-create").on('touchstart',(function(event)

Comment: Sorry but that doesent work..Any more suggestions? @Sushil

Comment: oh. there is an extra bracket. use this.   $("#button-create").on('touchstart',function(event) . note. there is an extra '(' before function, i've removed that. is this only going to be used on the phone @Anton?

Comment: Can't get it to work. Can you post a fiddle on it? @Sushil

Comment: here's the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/d87md5u0/

Comment: Thanks! The alert works but the ajax is not running.. @Sushil

Comment: something is wrong with the ajax then. let me see if i can update the fiddle with something

Comment: can you just try $("#stage").load('result.php')? and see if it is loading up correctly or try some other page

Comment: Okey I tested to delete the type"" from script and it starts to work, but only if I hold the button for some milisecond.  @Sushil

Comment: it should work with just a normal touch

Comment: But it doesent.. The animation runs good but if the ajax should work I most hold it a very short second @Sushil

Comment: Please try to solve this with me.. @Sushil

Comment: sorry @Anton was out on lunch. can u share the html? also when u debug, do you get something in the code?

Comment: Sorry was sleeping. I have debug it with a simple html site and that work greate on the phone. So maybe something wrong with the variables? But it work on computer.... Look on the updated question for the html. PS: The animation is under the ajax script.@Sushil

Comment: So after more debug I can say that the result.php doesent load in on the mobile. I added an echo but that did't run so none of the result.php code works in the phone. So what ca nbe the problem? Why doesent it run on the mobile? @Sushil

Comment: Update: It runs on second click.

Comment: I don't know php. but lets continue this on monday. have a great weekend.